# multi-target .NET Core project - error referencing types in other assemblies

Tags: .net-core

I have a couple of referencing errors in Dna.Net.Core.Smtp project:

> The type or namespace name 'ISystemSetting_Queries' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   Dna.Net.Core.Smtp..NET Framework 4.6.2

- "ISystemSetting_Queries" does exist in the Dna.Net.Core.BLL project
- all of the project.json files are restoring packages successfully
- Dna.Net.Core.Smtp is the only project referencing "net462"

The other issue is:

> The type or namespace name 'Mail' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

When I hover over System.Net.Mail, a dialog pops up saying:

> namespace: System.Net.Mail
>
> Dna.Net.Core.Smtp..NET Framework 4.6.2 - Available
>
> Dna.Net.Core.Smtp..NET Standard, Version=1.6 - Not Available
>
> you can use the navigation bar to switch context

The navigation bar shows Dna.Net.Core.Smtp..NET Framework 4.6.2 as the current selection.

Here are the project.json files:

**Dna.Net.Core.Smtp.project.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core.Smtp",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",  
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "net462": {},
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Dna.Net.Core": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Dna.Net.Core.BLL": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Dna.Net.Core.DAL.EF": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**Dna.Net.Core.DAL.EF.project.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core.DAL.EF",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Dna.Net.Core": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        },
        "Dna.Net.Core.BLL": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**Dna.Net.Core.BLL.project.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core.BLL",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.1.0",
    "AutoMapper": "5.1.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0",
    "System.Security.Claims": "4.0.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Dna.Net.Core": {
          "version": "1.0.0-*",
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

**Dna.Net.Core.project.json**

```
{
  "name": "Dna.Net.Core",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Autofac": "4.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives": "4.1.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong with this picture?

Comment: A library cannot target netstandard 1.6 if it rely on System.Net.Mail. And that applies to all libraries depending on this library afterwards.

Comment: _"...and that applies to all libraries depending on this library afterwards."_ Does this mean that if I removed the netstandard 1.6 dependency from the Dna.Net.Core.Smtp project, then it still would not be possible for an asp.net core application to depend on Dna.Net.Core.Smtp?

Comment: ASP.NET Core can run on net462, so the answer to your question is "yes, it is possible". But again, it won't run cross platform. By the way System.Net.Mail is coming in netstandard 2.0 if I am correct, so any barrier is temporary.